# Simple Neural Network built from scratch is not learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have implemented a neural network class that always has just a single hidden layer, using no libraries - not even numpy. I have done everything such the way that I understood it should be, but it is not learning at all, the loss is actually continuously increasing and I cannot find where I have gone wrong, even after looking at many examples online.

Here is my MLP class and a demo of it attempting to learn the XOR function:

```
import random
from math import exp


class MLP:

    def __init__(self, numInputs, numHidden, numOutputs):
        # MLP architecture sizes
        self.numInputs = numInputs
        self.numHidden = numHidden
        self.numOutputs = numOutputs

        # MLP weights
        self.IH_weights = [[random.random() for i in range(numHidden)] for j in range(numInputs)]
        self.HO_weights = [[random.random() for i in range(numOutputs)] for j in range(numHidden)]

        # Gradients corresponding to weight matrices computed during backprop
        self.IH_gradients = [[0 for i in range(numHidden)] for j in range(numInputs)]
        self.HO_gradients = [[0 for i in range(numOutputs)] for j in range(numHidden)]

        # Input, hidden and output neuron values
        self.I = None
        self.H = [0 for i in range(numHidden)]
        self.O = [0 for i in range(numOutputs)]

        self.H_deltas = [0 for i in range(numHidden)]
        self.O_deltas = [0 for i in range(numOutputs)]

    # Sigmoid
    def activation(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + exp(-x))

    # Derivative of Sigmoid
    def activationDerivative(self, x):
        return x * (1 - x)

    # Squared Error
    def calculateError(self, prediction, label):
        return (prediction - label) ** 2

    def forward(self, input):
        self.I = input
        for i in range(self.numHidden):
            for j in range(self.numInputs):
                self.H[i] += self.I[j] * self.IH_weights[j][i]
            self.H[i] = self.activation(self.H[i])

        for i in range(self.numOutputs):
            for j in range(self.numHidden):
                self.O[i] += self.activation(self.H[j] * self.HO_weights[j][i])
            self.O[i] = self.activation(self.O[i])

        return self.O

    def backwards(self, label):
        if label != list:
            label = [label]

        error = 0
        for i in range(self.numOutputs):
            neuronError = self.calculateError(self.O[i], label[i])
            error += neuronError
            self.O_deltas[i] = neuronError * self.activationDerivative(self.O[i])
            for j in range(self.numHidden):
                self.HO_gradients[j][i] += self.O_deltas[i] * self.H[j]

        for i in range(self.numHidden):
            neuronError = 0
            for j in range(self.numOutputs):
                neuronError += self.HO_weights[i][j] * self.O_deltas[j]
            self.H_deltas[i] = neuronError * self.activationDerivative(self.H[i])
            for j in range(self.numInputs):
                self.IH_gradients[j][i] += self.H_deltas[i] * self.I[j]

        return error

    def updateWeights(self, learningRate):
        for i in range(self.numInputs):
            for j in range(self.numHidden):
                self.IH_weights[i][j] += learningRate * self.IH_gradients[i][j]

        for i in range(self.numHidden):
            for j in range(self.numOutputs):
                self.HO_weights[i][j] += learningRate * self.HO_gradients[i][j]

        self.IH_gradients = [[0 for i in range(self.numHidden)] for j in range(self.numInputs)]
        self.HO_gradients = [[0 for i in range(self.numOutputs)] for j in range(self.numHidden)]


data = [
    [[0, 0], 0],
    [[0, 1], 1],
    [[1, 0], 1],
    [[1, 1], 0]
]

mlp = MLP(2, 5, 1)

for epoch in range(100):
    epochError = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        mlp.forward(data[i][0])
        epochError += mlp.backwards(data[i][1])
    print(epochError / len(data))
    mlp.updateWeights(0.001)
```

Comment: Why aren't you using numpy? That's going to make implementing the matrix multiplication routines really tedious. I'd recommend abstracting out functionality like that so that it becomes easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your implementation correctly, then your problem I believe is in the calculation of the weight updates in the backwards function, the update should be the error (not error squared) multiplied by the sigmoid derivative, so I would take a look/redo the calculations.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything - the loss still keeps consistently increasing

Comment: @KOB It doesn't that true, I tried the corrected code myself, so it seems you might have a problem in addition to this one. I would suggest you rewrite the backpropagation function and put sanity checks in your code to see where the problem is happening. I am sorry I wasn't more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

How did you go with this?  I showed it to a friend - we both found your goal of doing the algorithm without much abstraction was edifying, although trying to find errors is difficult.

The improvement he found is that updateWeights needs to be a negative feedback loop, so change "+=" to "-=" in two lines giving:

```
self.IH_weights[i][j] -= learningRate * self.IH_gradients[i][j]
```

and

```
self.HO_weights[i][j] -= learningRate * self.HO_gradients[i][j]
```

The other factor is increasing the learning rate. With these changes, the error descends to about 16% (for me, I may have made another change that I am not seeing) before it begins to climb asymptoting to 27% - maybe due to overtraining with a learning rate that is too high.

I made the learning rate dependent on the epoch

```
mlp.updateWeights(0.1/(0.01 * (epoch+1)))
```

and its decreases steadily and stabilizes at 0.161490...

But if you get the prediction from 'forward', its always predicting 0.66 - the inputs have been wiped away.  So... that's bad.

```
 - Input Data: [0, 0] | Prediction: [0.6610834017294481] |Truth: 0
 - Input Data: [0, 1] | Prediction: [0.6616502691118376] |Truth: 1
 - Input Data: [1, 0] | Prediction: [0.6601936411430607] |Truth: 1
 - Input Data: [1, 1] | Prediction: [0.6596122207209283] |Truth: 0
```

Comment: I have since implemented it using numpy and got it working properly - my backprop implementation was wrong. I was using the actual error at the output in backprop, rather than its derivative. I am now working on removing the numpy dependency again, just for fun.

Comment: Here is another question of mine where the numpy implementation was completed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754939/multilayer-perceptron-works-fine-with-sigmoid-activations-but-not-with-hyperbol/49758402?noredirect=1#comment86535759_49758402