# Multilayer Perceptron works fine with sigmoid activations, but not with hyperbolic tangent

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have written a simple MLP with one single layer. When learning the XOR function using sigmoid activations, the loss reduced consistently. However, if I change the labels of the XOR data from [0, 1] to [-1, 1] and use the tanh activation instead, the loss doesn't reduce. It should still work by simply changing the labels and using tanh, shouldn't it? And if so, where is my implementation going wrong with tanh?

```
import sys

import numpy as np


class DataSet:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.size = len(data)
        self.inputs, self.labels = [], []
        for i in range(len(data)):
            self.inputs.append(data[i][0])
            self.labels.append(data[i][1])
        try:
            self.numInputs = len(self.inputs[0])
        except TypeError:
            self.numInputs = 1
        try:
            self.numOutputs = len(self.labels[0])
        except TypeError:
            self.numOutputs = 1


class MLP:

    def __init__(self, numInputs, numHidden, numOutputs, activationFunction):
        # MLP architecture sizes
        self.numInputs = numInputs
        self.numHidden = numHidden
        self.numOutputs = numOutputs
        self.activationFunction = activationFunction.lower()

        # MLP weights
        self.IH_weights = np.random.rand(numInputs, numHidden)      # Input -> Hidden
        self.HO_weights = np.random.rand(numHidden, numOutputs)     # Hidden -> Output

        # Gradients corresponding to weight matrices computed during backprop
        self.IH_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.IH_weights)
        self.HO_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.HO_weights)

        # Input, hidden and output neuron values
        self.I = np.zeros(numInputs)    # Inputs
        self.L = np.zeros(numOutputs)   # Labels
        self.H = np.zeros(numHidden)    # Hidden
        self.O = np.zeros(numOutputs)   # Output

    # ADD BIAS FOR RELU ########################################################
    # ADD SOFTMAX ##############################################################
    def activation(self, x, derivative=False):
        if self.activationFunction == 'sigmoid':
            if derivative:
                return x * (1 - x)
            return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

        if self.activationFunction == 'tanh':
            if derivative:
                return 1. - np.tanh(x) ** 2
            return np.tanh(x)

        # if self.activationFunction == 'softmax':
        #     if derivative:
        #         return ########
        #     return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x))

        if self.activationFunction == 'relu':
            if derivative:
                return (x > 0).astype(float)
            return np.maximum(0, x)

        print("ERROR: Activation function not found.")
        sys.exit()

    def forward(self, inputs):
        # Ensure that inputs is a list
        try:
            len(inputs)
        except TypeError:
            inputs = [inputs]

        self.I = np.array(inputs).reshape(1, self.numInputs)
        self.H = self.I.dot(self.IH_weights)
        self.H = self.activation(self.H)
        self.O = self.H.dot(self.HO_weights)
        self.O = self.activation(self.O)
        return self.O, self.L

    def backwards(self, labels):
        # Ensure that labels is a list
        try:
            len(labels)
        except TypeError:
            labels = [labels]

        self.L = np.array(labels)
        self.O_error = self.L - self.O
        self.O_delta = self.O_error * self.activation(self.O, derivative=True)

        self.H_error = self.O_delta.dot(self.HO_weights.T)
        self.H_delta = self.H_error * self.activation(self.H, derivative=True)

        self.IH_gradients += self.I.T.dot(self.H_delta)
        self.HO_gradients += self.H.T.dot(self.O_delta)

        return np.sum(self.O_error ** 2)

    def updateWeights(self, learningRate):
        self.IH_weights += self.IH_gradients
        self.HO_weights += self.HO_gradients
        self.IH_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.IH_weights)
        self.HO_gradients = np.zeros_like(self.HO_weights)

# data = DataSet([
#     [[0, 0], 0],
#     [[0, 1], 1],
#     [[1, 0], 1],
#     [[1, 1], 0]
# ])
#
# mlp = MLP(data.numInputs, 20, data.numOutputs, 'sigmoid')

data = DataSet([
    [[0, 0], -1],
    [[0, 1], 1],
    [[1, 0], 1],
    [[1, 1], -1]
])

mlp = MLP(data.numInputs, 20, data.numOutputs, 'tanh')

numEpochs = 10000
learningRate = 0.01

losses = []
for epoch in range(numEpochs):
    errors = []
    correct = []
    for i in range(data.size):
        mlp.forward(data.inputs[i])
        errors.append(mlp.backwards(data.labels[i]))
    mlp.updateWeights(learningRate)
    epochLoss = np.mean(errors)
    losses.append(epochLoss)
    if epoch % 100 == 0 or epoch == numEpochs - 1:
        print("EPOCH:", epoch)
        print("LOSS: ", epochLoss, "\n")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample your network is failing to predict is ([0,0], -1), which is a result of the lack of bias. For I = [0,0], we have H = dot(Wh,I) = [0,0,..0]. Since tanh(0) = 0, the network is unable to learn any transformation of zero to non-zero at any layer. Adding bias will solve the issue; a hacky solution can be achieved by adding a 3rd column to your dataset filled with any constant, to emulate the effect of bias.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not seem to make any difference. I have also seen people using just `return 1. - x ** 2`, presumably for a similar reason. This, too, did not work for me.

Comment: For me, both ways is constantly producing a loss of just over 0.25 (it slowly decreases tiny amounts per epoch, but never below 0.25). Using sigmoid, the loss reduces far rapidly to a far lower value. Did you change anything else?

Comment: Give me a moment and I'll get back to you

Comment: I have actually just found my problem. I was never multiplying the gradients by the learning rate in `updateWeights`, so I think it that particular case, it was "jumping back and forth" across the valley of the loss function.

Comment: Nevermind, that just allows the loss to reduce far slower towards 0.25. Maybe 0.25 is actually a very low loss, but I am just expecting it to be lower as it is far lower when the labels and predictions are within half the range using sigmoid than they are with tanh. I will investigate.

Comment: Sorry, had to run some chores for a moment. The sample you cant learn is actually [0,0] which makes sense since your hidden layer dotted with zeros gives zeros, which in turn dotted with your output layer again return zeros. Additionally, tanh(0) = 0. So your network will never be able to learn to transform [0,0] to a non-zero value. Just adding a 3rd column on your input data, filled with a constant to emulate bias will let your network learn stuff.

Comment: I am actually adding in a bias into my MLP class now, and am already seeing results from using the bias in the forward pass, without having implemented the backprop bias calculations yet. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad to help and congrats on your code, it's very easy to follow. I'm editing the original answer.

Comment: One more similar follow up - is there a similar reason as to why this is not working with relu, even with the biases added? It converges to exactly 0.25. Here is my code with the biases added, if you'd like to check if I have done so correctly. https://pastebin.com/bUUruC5G

Comment: Can't think of anything right off my head but I'll check it in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Actually, having just two hidden neurons (which is what I was using to test) causes relu to converge to 0.25, but changing to just 3 neurons allows relu to learn far, far quicker than sigmoid and tanh, even when they use 10x as many neurons. Interesting!

Comment: Even with 2 neurons and a LR of 1e-02 it is converging for me

Comment: Great, so everything seems to be working well. Now I just need to implement softmax and cross entropy too.

Comment: The 0.25 problem is a side-effect of sgd and random weight initialization, sometimes you'll get stuck there and sometimes you won't. The way around it would be to boost your learning rate whenever your errors are the same as the last epoch errors.

Comment: Yes I was suspicious as to why it would sometimes happen, and sometimes not. Thanks again for all the help